# How to write a mathematical equation for GLM model with gamma and gaussian distribution?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction

I am writing a paper and the following is a code that I wrote in R. The reason that I am struggling with this is because I tried hundreds of models with different variables and the following model below had the best model with the least MAPE. I added and multiplied some variables and I am not sure how my model should be expressed in a mathematical equation and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

FYI, B_1 is a categorical variable and the rest are numerical variables.

```
model = glm(as.formula(y ~ (B_1+B_2)*B_3*B_4*B_5), data = train.set, family="Gamma")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Be clearer about what you need help with. What does gamma or gaussian have to do with it? And that formula appears to imply more than 5 parameters.

Comment: @PeterEllis As I wrote in the question, I need to figure out a way to express the model in R code in a mathematical equation. I cannot give away more specific information about each variable as the project itself is pretty confidential. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very standard GLM so why not just take it from a textbook?  That's why I meant "what is the particular difficulty".  If you can't say more than that about what you don't understand it's difficult to help.  As a starter, do you want to express it in linear algebra or not?  Are you worried about how to express the linear predictor, or is it the equation for the density of a Gamma distributed response that is problematic?  I'd hate to write an answer on the Gamma pdf only to find that it was interactions you didn't understand.

Comment: @PeterEllis I looked at many books and there are no equations multiplying some of variables. I understand the part about adding variables, but multiplying variables.. how am I supposed to write that into an equation? Yes, I am worried about how to express the variables in a mathematical equation as I mentioned twice already.

Comment: One thing to note is that the default link for the Gamma family is the inverse link. This is pretty obscure; be sure that you really want it, and not (say) the log link which is much more common in practice.

Comment: @HongOoi I don't understand what you mean by log link. Are you referring to Poisson distribution or taking log in gamma distribution?  Can you explain why the log link is much more common in practice?